# Drag and drop doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I get an issue when I execute my code on IE, everything works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE.

My code :

```
        $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
        $cases.children('div').on('mouseenter', function(){
            $cases.on({
                dragstart: function(e) {
                    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', $(this).text());
                },
                dragenter: function(e) {

                    console.log('data == '+ e.dataTransfer.getData('text')); // RETURN NOTHING

                    $(this).addClass('onDraggableElement');
                    var $expendCase = $(this).children('div');
                    $(this).html(e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
                    $(this).append($expendCase);
                    e.preventDefault();
                },
                dragleave: function(e) {},
                dragover: function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                },
                drop: function(e) {},
                dragend: function(e) {
                    $('td[draggable="true"').removeClass('onDraggableElement');
                    unselectCase();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Of which version of IE are we talking about? Which version of jQuery UI?

Comment: No version of jQuery UI, pure jQuery... And it's about IE 11...